# Why is const int faster than const int&?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I noticed this accidentally one day, and now decided to test it extensively.

So, when I call a function:

```
#define Type int
#define Prm const Type &
Type testfunc1(Prm v1, Prm v2, Prm v3, Prm v4, Prm v5, Prm v6, Prm v7, Prm v8, Prm v9, Prm v10){
    return (v1|v2|v3|v4|v5|v6|v7|v8|v9|v10);
}
```

100 million times:

```
        for(Type y = 0; y < 10000; y++){
            for(Type x = 0; x < 10000; x++){
                out |= testfunc1(x,y,x,x,y,y,x,y,x,y);
            }
        }
```

With types `int`, `const int` and `const int &`, i notice that `const int` is faster than `const int &`. (Note: im using the return value to ensure the function wont get optimized off).

Why is it so? I always thought adding `&` would actually make it faster, but the tests say the opposite. I know for bigger datatypes it would probably be different outcome, I didnt test those though since I'm quite sure about the results.

My tests:

```
const int: 7.95s
const int &: 10.2s
```

**Edit:** I think it is indeed because of my architecture; I tested with `Sint64` type and the results were:

```
const Sint64: 17.5s
const Sint64 &: 16.2s
```

**Edit2:** Or is it? Tested with `double` type (which is 64bit?), and results make me puzzled:

```
const double: 11.28s
const double &: 12.34s
```

Edit3: updated the loop code to match my newest tests with 64bit types.

Comment: Using the return value as you did doesn't ensure it will not get optimized off. As is, the whole computation can be done at compile time, so the compiler can optimize everything out, replacing the loops with simply `0x3FFF`.

Comment: I'll be interested in the answer to this. It may be that a const int is treated differently by the function prolog code (put in by the compiler) than a const int &. I'm taking an educated guess.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, well, if it did optimize it off, it wouldnt execute it for 7.95 seconds ;) not to mention my compiler isnt that smart for sure (it managed to optimize it only if i gave constant values for the parameters).

Comment: One reason to prefer inline functions is that the compiler can often optimize the two cases to be the same.

Comment: Did you actually compile with -O2 or -O3 (or release mode on windows)?

Comment: @LokiAstari -O2 im using, and release mode on windows yes.

Comment: Maybe he's running in a 64bit or above addressing system where the addresses eats 8 bytes compared to int(4bytes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By putting a `&` into the argument, you are adding more code to the program. Without the `&`, the sequence is:

```
 push values
 call Function
 pop values <- usually an update to stack pointer
```

and in Function:

```
 return sp[arg1] | sp[arg2] | etc <- value read direct from stack.
```

Adding the '&' does this:

```
 push address of value1
 push address of value2
 etc
 call Function
 pop values <- usually an update to stack pointer
```

and in Function:

```
 return_value = 0;
 address = sp[arg1]
 or return_value, [address]
 address = sp[arg2]
 or return_value, [address]
 etc
 return return_value
```

So, as you can see, the `&` adds a lot. So why use it? If you have a very large object, passing a pointer is more optimal than copying the object to the stack.

Comment: I should also add that the above is a general description. Optimisers may put values into registers rather than the stack. The IA64 compilers may also put arguments into registers.

Comment: plus 1 for mentioning the registers.

Answer (score 7):

This result is heavily system-dependent. It indicates that on your particular system copying a value of a reference (which is most likely implemented as a pointer) has higher cost than copying a value of an integer. The most probable reason for that difference is that your integer requires 32-bits to represent, and your pointer/reference representation requires 64-bits. **EDIT** This is not to mention the cost of *accessing* your integers: getting their values would require an additional indirection. Since you are passing only two items, use of caching hides that additional cost to a large extent, but the cost is there.

You are absolutely right about larger types, though: passing a reference to, say, a large `struct` or a `vector<...>` still requires only 64 bit (or whatever that size is on your system), regardless of how many items your structure has, or how many items your `vector<...>` holds. The larger the structure, the higher the costs to pass it by value, and therefore the savings that you realize by making it a reference.

Comment: Even if a pointer requires only 32-bits, accessing the actual int value would require one indirection, which may account for the difference.

Comment: Even if copying the `int` were more expensive than copying the address, the reference version also involves an indirect memory fetch operation which is likely equal in cost to copying an `int`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You are correct, there is a cost of indirection. The test in the OP is structured in a way to hide that cost somewhat, because he will be passing addresses of only two variables instead of ten, so eight indirect accesses would be serviced by the cache, but your are right, the cost is still there.

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right, I edited the answer to mention this difference.

Comment: i think this is correct; i tested with 64bit integers and now `const Sint64 &` is slightly faster! So, it is because my CPU is 64bit? does this mean that 32bit CPU will make `const Sint32 &` faster than `const Sint32` ?

Comment: @Rookie: Computers are complicated beasts. While you can make educated guesses, you generally **cannot** get the answer to questions like that with pure reason -- you actually have to test it out. (and sometimes, the surrounding code an even influence which is faster!)

Comment: @Hurkyl You are absolutely right! It looks like I guessed it right this time (see OP's edit), but that does not make your point about testing it out less valuable. Thanks!

Comment: I made another test with `double` type: `&` makes it slower! that is weird. any idea on that?

Comment: @Rookie This is probably a result of an additional indirection: the sizes are identical, but the CPU needs to first read the address, and then the double (vs. simply getting a double, perhaps even from a register, which is orders of magnitude faster).

Comment: I've been thinking, would it be smart if i didnt use `&` for 32bit and smaller sized variables? since in the future everyone will have 64bit CPU's anyways and i dont want to make my program slower on 64bit; all the advertising says 64bit should be faster. Somehow the code also looks better when only bigger datatypes have the longer version for the function parameter, in a way showing that it is important there to have all that.

Comment: @Rookie Use the data type that makes most sense to *a human reader of your program*, not to a computer. In general, when you know the exact type at the time of writing your program, there should be no doubt in your mind as to what that type should be (it's the type that makes most sense *to you*). There are situations when you have no idea of the exact type: specifically, when you define a function or a class template, you should assume that any type that *could* be plugged in *will* be plugged in. In this case, use of `const &` is preferred, because it is fast for both large and small types.

Answer (score 2):

Passing addresses instead of values causes the addresses to escape (look up escape analysis or points-to analysis in your favorite compiler textbook), making optimization more difficult.

Yes, things like inlining and link-time optimization can mitigate these issues.